# Visa on arrival in Singapore Changi Airport

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, airports, singapore

I am in Indian national studying in China.  I am travelling to China - Fuzhou from India (bangalore) Via Singapore Changi Airport.  My itinerary is as below:

```
Departure  Arrival    From                      To           Flight  Dep.      Arr.      Airline  PNR No
                                                             No.     Terminal  Terminal

09 FEB 20  10 FEB 20  Bangalore                 Singapore    G827    4*                  GOAIR   
19:50      03:20      Kempegowda International  Changi, SIN
                      Airport, BLR
5h 0m

LAYOVER 7h 25m

10 FEB 20  10 FEB 20  Singapore                 Fuzhou       TR174   -*        -*        
10:45      15:05      Changi, SIN               Fuzhou, FOC

4h 20m
```

I need to clear luggage and rebook in Singapore.  Do I need Visa on arrival for lay over time of 7 hrs 25 minutes.  I do not intend to go out of the airport.  Please guide me.  Thanks and regards  Vinay

Comment: Do you have visa for any other countries like US, Canada, etc?

Comment: you should probably not post your PNR publicly

Answer (score 2):

You can call the airlines and check if baggage connection option is available from the transfer counter located airside. In that case, after arriving at Singapore airside, you can visit transfer counter of onward airline and connect your bag and get boarding pass, airside.

**UPDATE:** As far as I'm aware there is no third-party baggage connection service in Singapore. Both GoAir and Scoot are low-cost carriers and do not interline.

The Visa Free Transit Facility (VFTF) is available for people with visa of specific countries.

From - https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf

> If you are in transit to or from any third country via Singapore, you
>   may be eligible for the 96-hour VFTF if you meet these requirements:
>
> - You may enter Singapore by any mode of transport but depart only via    air or sea.
> - You must have a valid onward air/ferry/cruise ticket    departing Singapore within 96 hours; and
> - You must have a valid visa*/long-term pass (with a validity of at least 1 month from the date of entry into Singapore under the VFTF)
>     issued by any of the following countries:
> - Australia
> - Canada
> - Germany^
> - Japan
> - New Zealand
> - Switzerland^
> - United Kingdom
> - United States of America
>
> A visa is considered valid so long as it is good for entry into one of
>   the eight countries listed above. Travellers with Single Journey Visas
>   (SJV) may still be granted VFTF on the return leg of their journey
>   (i.e. after the SJV is used and no longer valid), but you must:
>
> - Travel directly from the country that issued the SJV, en route through Singapore, back to your home country
> - Not have returned to your home country since you last used the SJV.
>
> ^ Applies to visas issued by Germany or Switzerland, or Schengen visas
>   that are good for entry to Germany or Switzerland.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no third-party baggage connection service in Singapore.  Both GoAir and Scoot are low-cost carriers and do not interline.